# Docker php-fpm/nginx set-up: php-fpm throwing blank 500, no error logs

Tags: php, nginx, docker, error-logging

Git repo of project: https://github.com/tombusby/docker-laravel-experiments (HEAD at time of writing is 823fd22).

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
nginx:
  image: nginx:stable
  volumes:
    - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
  volumes_from:
    - php
  links:
    - php:php
  ports:
    - 80:80

php:
  image: php:5.6-fpm
  volumes:
    - ./src:/var/www/html
  expose:
    - 9000
```

Into src/ I've created a fresh laravel project. This all functions correctly if I swap out index.php for one with a basic `echo "hello world";` and if I use `echo "called";exit();` I can identify that part of laravel's index.php does get executed.

It dies at line 53:

```
$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);
```

I have no idea why this happens, and I've tried using `docker exec -it <cid> bash` to have a look around my php-fpm container for error logs. All the logs are redirected to stderr/stdout (which is collected by docker).

Here is the output that docker collects:

```
php_1   | 172.17.0.3 -  06/May/2016:12:09:34 +0000 "GET /index.php" 500
nginx_1 | 192.168.99.1 - - [06/May/2016:12:09:34 +0000] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 500 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

As you can see "500" does pretty much nothing to help me work out why there was an error, but I can't find any way of getting the stack trace or anything like the proper error logs that apache's php extension would have produced.

Comment: I'm facing a _very_ similar issue... did you ever find the root cause of the problem?

Comment: The accepted answer will solve your issue. The default php-fpm config from the official docker iamge has errors turned off. If you try to enable it with `ini_set` or similar then php-fpm ignores that. You need to set it in the php-fpm config file using `php_admin_flag[log_errors]`. I did this by having my docker compose mount a costom php-fpm config file over the top of the existing one as a read-only volume.

Comment: Also, if this question describes a problem you're having, then upvotes are always appreciated ;)

Comment: Done. Actually, I meant that your base issue (Laravel not working, not logs not working) sounded very similar. In the end I did enable logging as suggested and found out that the problem was with permissions of bootstrap/cache and storage directories. Adding RUN chmod -R 777 to the Dockerfile solved the issue. Not entirely sure if there are more elegant solutions, though.

Comment: Ahhh, ok, sure. Yeah you can 777 your permissions, but if that makes you feel dirty: `user = 1000` and `group = staff` in your php-fpm.conf will fix the permissions issues (for mac docker, but probs cause them for linux hosts).

Comment: You can also sign up for native Docker for OSX beta now. I have access but I haven't used it yet. It doesn't use a Linux virtualbox vm so in theory those permissions issues shouldn't occur, since it can run from your own filesystem.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As per our discussion in ##php on freenode...

Your issue is that the php.ini setting "log_errors" is set to Off.

your options are:

- set log_errors=On in php.ini
- set php_admin_flag[log_errors]=On in your pool config (for docker container based on `php:5.6-fpm` that is in the file `/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf`)
- or possibly set log_errors=On in .user.ini (php's per-dir config, similar to .htaccess)

Comment: finally something that works, I've been searching for this for too long!
`php_admin_flag[log_errors]=On`

Answer (score -2):

As I can see your are running request by a Mac, is the docker environment set up on Mac also?
If it is can you, by running bash on the php-fpm container, try to write into the exposed volume? (`/var/www/html` on the container)

Comment: That's not the issue. Everything is working correctly for a basic hello world app. My issue is that I get a 500, and I want to see the logs to find out why that happened. I can't find any logs.

Comment: What do yo mean for a "hello world app"?

Comment: as in, "hello world":

Comment: <?php
    echo "hello world";

Comment: I think we're getting confused here: I just want to know how to get the logs. I'm not as interested in solving what's causing the error, as I am in getting the error logs themselves.

Comment: Running your docker compose on a correctly set up docker env on Mac OS X leads to the following result:
`Warning: require(/var/www/html/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /var/www/html/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17`
So I think the problem here is the incorrect docker env that makes fpm throw a fatal error that is not correctly logged.

Comment: ...that's because you haven't run composer install.

Answer (score -2):

Try to give access to storage folder:

```
chmod -R 777 storage
```